# Copy a wifi module from Ubuntu to RemixOS?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, android

I have installed RemixOS on my Laptop (sony vaio SVF 1521V1EB) but the Wifi is not working. I could make it work on Ubuntu, so can copy the module files from Ubuntu and insert them into the RemixOS (Android) kernel? They both share the Linux 3.x kernel. If yes, how can I collect all the files that I have to move into the Droid kernel?